# How getRowTotalInclTax() is calculated for magento cart page

Tags: cart, price, magento1.9.2.4

I am facing a problem in which row total of products are not taking special price for some products. I need to check the calculation from where it is calculated.

Anyone who knows the file in which it is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

This value calculated in app\code\core\Mage\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Subtotal.php
Depends on selected algorithm, it use

```
 protected function _processItem($item, $taxRequest)
{
    switch ($this->_config->getAlgorithm($this->_store)) {
        case Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation::CALC_UNIT_BASE:
            $this->_unitBaseCalculation($item, $taxRequest);
            break;
        case Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation::CALC_ROW_BASE:
            $this->_rowBaseCalculation($item, $taxRequest);
            break;
        case Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation::CALC_TOTAL_BASE:
            $this->_totalBaseCalculation($item, $taxRequest);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

So, check the function that is used in your case. Also you can search for this row:

```
$item->setRowTotalInclTax($taxSubtotal);
```

Comment: Can you tell me when this methods are called? When row total is calculated for a particular product?

Comment: This method is called when subtotal is calculated. During this calculation system go throw all items and also fill this values.

Comment: Thats what I want to know,  when subtotal is calculated. I am facing an issue in which subtotal is showing original price in place of special price. I need to check why?

Comment: Sure, you can debug it in this place. Using xdebug for example